# JVM Fatal Error

Tags: jvm, jvm-crash

I have updated by JDK 4 months back to 1.6.0_45 in my **SOLARIS SPRAC Machine**, till yesterday it went well without any issues, but yesterday unfortunately i got an fatal error as below and the instance get crashed, as a work around i have restarted my server instance and it up and running fine now.

I need to know,

- whats the exact root cause for this error?
- How to investigate this ?
- How can i avoid this in near future?

**A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:**

> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xfebd390c, pid=2626, tid=3
>
> JRE version: 6.0_45-b06
>    Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (20.45-b01 mixed mode solaris-sparc )
>    Problematic frame:
>    V [libjvm.so+0x7d390c]  void PSScavenge::copy_and_push_safe_barrier(PSPromotionManager*,__type_0*)+0xcc
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Your JVM did crash inside libjvm.so, while doing GC. You can try changing the GC methodology (for example, try using -XX:+UseParallelOldGC) as meanwhile alternative. Else best bet would be to update the JVM.